# Simplifying a short list comparison

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, comparison, simplify

Here's the code. It's being used to change a certain value stored in a list (of between 25 and 81 values), depending on the user input. I'm using a second list to decide what happens, with only 4 values inside, which were also the user's input. Basically, if the user chooses a certain value, it changes to the next value in sequence.

```
if list1[value] == list2[3]:
    list[value] = list2[0]
elif list1[value] == list2[0]:
    list[value] = list2[1]
elif list1[value] == list2[1]:
    list[value] = list2[2]
elif list1[value] == list2[2]:
    list[value] = list2[3]
```

My problem is, I can't find a way to make it simpler. It looks quite long and ugly. It also needs to be executed many times based on extra inputs, so, if the user chose the same variable twice, it would change each time, in sequence.

This seems like such a dumb problem. I've been trying to think of how to simplify this for ages, to a short for loop or something, but for some reason fail every time.
I've tried something like this:

```
e = value % 4
if list1[value] == list2[e]:
    list1[value] = list2[e + 1]
#This isn't exactly what I had, but something along these lines, maybe in a for loop too etc.
```

List 2 contains 4 string, [colour1, colour2, colour3, colour4]
List 1 contains these same strings, but looped over and over until it hits the list limit specified by user.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What do the lists look like?

Comment: list 2 has 4 strings, [userColor1, userColor2, userColor3, userColor4]
List 1 will have between 25 and 81 values, same strings as list 2, but looping over and over until it hits the max amount of values.

Comment: @Jett: Could you edit the question to add that comment into it? It'll be faster to see in once glance for future visitors. (the `edit` link under the list of tags)

Comment: @BorrajaX No prob, done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a list for the "cycle" set of data, use a dictionary of `{value: nextvalue}`, i.e.:

```
cycler = {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 0} # replace 0,1,2,3 with the actual values
if list1[value] in cycler:
    list1[value] = cycler[list1[value]]
```

EDIT: To build the cycler from a list of elements:

```
cycler = {list2[i-1]: list2[i] for i in xrange(len(list2))}
# Note that this works because `list2[-1]` indexes the last element.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works. One thing is though, I don't know what the actual values are until the user enters it, so it's a little bit long. Will I just have to live with entering {list2[0]: list2[1], list2[1], list2[2]} etc? If there's no way to simplify further then this is perfect!

Comment: @Jett added code to build the list more conveniently.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0, len(list2):
    if list1[value] == list2[i] :
        list1[value] = list2[(i+1)%len(list2)]
```